# How can I use multiple substring functions in an update statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, substring, concatenation

I have a table with a column called `candidate_name` in which the names are formatted as `lastname, firstname`. I'd like to update the column so that the names are in `firstname lastname` format.

I wrote this query to see if the string functions were working correctly:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(candidate_name, 1, LOCATE(',', candidate_name) - 1) AS last,
    SUBSTRING(candidate_name, LOCATE(',', candidate_name) + 2, LENGTH(candidate_name) - LOCATE(',', candidate_name) - 1) AS first
FROM 
    colorado_project.candidates
WHERE 
    candidate_name = 'AHREND, JARED';
```

This returns the strings into new columns as expected:

[image]

But I don't know how to use these in an update statement. I've tried many statements similar to this:

```
UPDATE candidates
SET candidate_name = SUBSTRING(candidate_name, 1, LOCATE(',', candidate_name) - 1),
                     SUBSTRING(candidate_name, LOCATE(',', candidate_name) + 2,
        LENGTH(candidate_name) - LOCATE(',', candidate_name) - 1)
WHERE candidate_name = 'AHREND, JARRED';
```

Pretty sure I've gotten every error known to mankind at this point, but the main error I get is

> '1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value 'AHREND'.

I've searched around and it seems like this error is often associated with comparing a string value to a number value, but I don't understand by the substring functions would be returning a number value now, when they were returning strings before? Or maybe that's not whats going on here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I'm not sure how to find the table definition, I'm still new to this. But the 'candidates' table is made up of text columns, with the exception of the 'candidate_name' column that I'm working with here. I changed it to a VARCHAR column in an effort to get this to work, but it didn't help.

I've also tagged MySQL and will remember to do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must concatenate the 2 parts of the name:

```
UPDATE candidates
SET candidate_name = CONCAT( 
  SUBSTRING(candidate_name, LOCATE(',', candidate_name) + 2, LENGTH(candidate_name) - LOCATE(',', candidate_name) - 1),
  ' ',
  SUBSTRING(candidate_name, 1, LOCATE(',', candidate_name) - 1)
)
WHERE candidate_name = 'AHREND, JARED';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97b96a4ea5e3009e167996143f1095f5).

or, simpler with [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
UPDATE candidates
SET candidate_name = CONCAT( 
  TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(candidate_name, ',', -1)),
  ' ',
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(candidate_name, ',', 1)
)
WHERE candidate_name = 'AHREND, JARED';
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26b0c1b66f021139d4e176b030077928).

Comment: This worked, thank you! I thought about using CONCAT, but convinced myself that wouldn't work for some reason. Now, looking at it, it makes total sense!